# Android BackupAgentHelper restoring preferences but changes not visible until after restart

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-backup-service

I've implemented the BackupAgentHelper into my android app. I'm backing up a couple of SharedPreferences files and some entities of my own with a custom helper.

I'm on API 22 and testing on a real device (Sony Z3 Compact).

The entity part of the backup and restore works fine, in that you can breakpoint through it and add logging and the entities are written out and read back in as expected. However, the preferences part only actually changes the preference values after a restart.

I've logged out the pref values in my agent's onRestore method, before the call to super.onRestore, and then again in onRestoreFinished, after the call to super.onRestore. The values are unchanged. However, if I restart and log the values out when I use them, they are as expected.

I've used the Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS flag to open my preferences for logging, but it's made no difference.

Something else interesting interesting is that I've registered an OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener that just logs out changed values, but it never gets fired.

I've been looking at this for a while now and I've looked at various issues people have had with retrieving the wrong values of preferences, but they all seem to point to using the MODE_MULTI_PROCESS flag. I've tried it and it didn't work. Also, this flag is deprecated in API 23, so doesn't seem like a long term solution anyway.

My code looks like this:

```
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();

    SharedPreferencesBackupHelper helper = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, MyApplication.PREFS_A)
    {
        @Override
        public void restoreEntity(BackupDataInputStream data)
        {
            super.restoreEntity(data);
            Logger.debug(FQCN, "Prefs A restore done. Current value A = {0}", getPrefValue("A"));
        }
    };
    addHelper(KEY_PREFS_A, helper);

    SharedPreferencesBackupHelper entityControllerPrefsHelper = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, MyApplication.PREFS_B)
    {
        @Override
        public void restoreEntity(BackupDataInputStream data)
        {
            super.restoreEntity(data);
            Logger.debug(FQCN, "Prefs B restore done. Current value B = {0}", getPrefValue("B"));
        }
    };

    addEntityHelpers();
}

public void onRestore(BackupDataInput data, int appVersionCode, ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException
{
    Logger.debug(FQCN, "About to restore. Current value A = {0}", getPrefValue("A"));

    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
        {
            Logger.stack(FQCN, "onRestore.onSharedPreferenceChanged. Key = {0}, Value = {1}", key, sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));
        }
    };
    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
    Logger.debug(FQCN, "About to restore. Current value B = {0}", getPrefValue("B"));

    super.onRestore(data, appVersionCode, newState);

    //Just to make sure the listener isn't GC'd while we're restoring.
    Logger.debug(FQCN, "listener hashcode. Not interesting. {0}", listener.hashCode());
}

public void onRestoreFinished()
{
    super.onRestoreFinished();

    Logger.debug(FQCN, "Restore finished. Current value A = {0}", getPrefValue("A"));

    Logger.debug(FQCN, "Restore finished. Current value B = {0}", getPrefValue("B"));
}

public String getPrefValue(String name)
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = MyApplication.get().getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
    return prefs.getString(name, "");
}
```

The logging goes like this...

```
Application.onCreate()  Current value A = def
Application.onCreate()  Current value B = uvw

<Backup>
<Uninstall via ADB>
<Install via ADB, following logging comes out when install completes>

D/BackupManagerService: initiateOneRestore packageName=blah
BackupAgentHelper.onRestore()   About to restore. Current value A = abc
BackupAgentHelper.onRestore()   About to restore. Current value B = xyz
SharedPreferencesBackupHelper.restoreEntity()   Prefs A restore done. Current value A = abc
SharedPreferencesBackupHelper.restoreEntity()   Prefs B restore done. Current value B = xyz
BackupAgentHelper.onRestoreFinished()   Restore finished. Current value A = abc
BackupAgentHelper.onRestoreFinished()   Restore finished. Current value B = xyz
I/BackupRestoreController: restoreFinished for 0
I/BackupManagerService: Restore complete.

<Restart>

Application.onCreate()  Current value A = def
Application.onCreate()  Current value B = uvw
```